# If Network Profile option can only be seen by me and mods, please allow only me and mods to view network profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-accounts, network-profile

I have my Super User and Stack Overflow and some more accounts hidden and so when I hover over network profile I get the message

> Only you and mods can see this link

It's good that this option is only available for moderators. However, if somehow someone obtains my Network Profile link, then my Network Profile can be seen by anyone. Like if I open my network profile link on guest window, it opens like

[image]

I want that even if someone has my network profile link, they still can't access it due to some personal reason, and only me and moderators can view the link. Can this be implemented, please?

Comment: The system is working as designed. The *link* to the network profile is only shown to you and mods on sites which you've marked as hidden. However, the profile *itself* is still publicly visible, with it not listing your site accounts.

Comment: You can't hide the network profile itself as it's not really a profile, it's a "portal", or "collection" of all your actual network profiles. So it won't make sense to not show it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I am asking that once me and mods can see network profile if they have link not others

Comment: @JitendraSingh others don't see a link anywhere, that's already the case. But if one happened to store the link locally, or go to locally cached page, I don't think it would make sense to give them 404 error on the network profile, as it's not deleted.

Comment: We can  give error like page not found because if you try to view a mods message and change the number for message number your receive other than that you only receive Page Not Found Error @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3

Comment: Ugh... I just realized the "network profile" link is gone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not technically feasible, at least without removing other useful information.

Even if the profile itself weren't visible, most of the contents could be recreated via SEDE queries to find all accounts with a given network ID.

Additionally, the profiles on individual sites could still be searched for if they have the same name, and they could be correlated by network ID through the API.  If they have different names, it's harder, but you could probably still find them if you looked hard enough and knew approximately when they were created.

Comment: Although the reason is not regarding showing my network profile the problem I have something else. Thanks for the answer though